# Retrieve default sshd_config file

Tags: raspbian, ssh, debian, packages

I updated Raspbian from Jessie to Stretch. During this update process I kept my existing `sshd_config` file and didn't update to the new one.

I'd now like to see the changes which come with the new `sshd_config` and merge them with my existing config file.

How can I retrieve the actual `sshd_config` file from the package repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is usually to move the existing file to some other place and reinstall the package:

```
mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.my
apt-get remove openssh-server
apt-get install openssh-server
diff /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.my
```

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get remove --purge openssh-server
apt-get install openssh-server
```

apt-get purge command removes the program package from your system without keeping the configuration files and any plugins and settings.